# how to blank input field after adding element in list?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to add item in `list` after click off `button` .But after click I want to **blank** input field after adding item .here is my code

https://plnkr.co/edit/0sG16dVeHIWAvBjYpIjQ?p=preview

```
export class App {
   title = 'Times point';
  name ="hellxo";
  val ="defual";
  items=[];
  onKeyP(event){
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.val=event.target.value
  }

  addItem(){
    if(this.val){
    this.items.push(this.val);
    this.val ='';
    }
  }
}
```

I already do empty value but not work
 **this.val ='';**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [value] ="val". [value] binds your input value with val. when ever val changes it will change automatically

use this line

```
<input type="text" name="" (keyup)="onKeyP($event)" [value]="val"/>
```

instead of

```
<input type="text" name="" (keyup)="onKeyP($event)"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ngModel directive to two-way databind the value of the input to a variable in your component.

In order to use the ngModel directive, you need to import the FormsModule into your component.

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
...
@NgModule({
    imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
    ...
})
```

When databinding the value to a variable in your component, you can just clear the value and angular will update the input field automatically.

I changed your plunkr to work with the ngModel:

https://plnkr.co/edit/uF2jkMeVxzgW5aKiqa7i?p=preview

An alternative approach would be to use @ViewChild(), to directly manipulate the HTML-Element.